# JavaScript array find fitting range

Tags: javascript

I have the following array with two objects:

```
var myArr = [{
  id: 3,
  licences: 100
  new_value_pr_licence: 40
}, {
  id: 4,
  licences: 200
  new_value_pr_licence: 25
}]
```

A user wish to buy 150 licences. This means that they fall into the category 100 because they are above 100 licences but below 200 which means they pay $40 per licence.

Note that the array object values varies.

Comment: `This means that he falls into the category 100 because he is above 100 licences but below 200 which means he pays 40$ pr licence` didn't get this part. How can someone who wants to buy 150 licenses fall in the category of 100?

Comment: The algorithm is just taking the wanted licenses, and calculating a total cost?

Comment: Well sorry category is a wrong word. he is in that price range which means he qualifys for the discount of 100 +

Comment: @gurvinder372 Because it is not enough to get the next, better discount/price

Comment: Unrelated side note: No-one would ever buy 150 licenses for 150*$40 = $6000 if they can buy 200 licenses for 200*$25 = $5000.

Comment: @Michael-R Yeah taking the wanted licenses and finding the right cost

Comment: @Juhana True but this is an example the price displayed is not something we use it is only for demonstration purposes

Comment: @MarcRasmussen Hey could you explain how the chosen answer helped you? And as opposed to mine whn you stated you needed a simple solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Order your plans by the price per licence:

```
myArr.sort(function (a, b) {
  return a.new_value_pr_licence - b.new_value_pr_licence;
})
```

then starting from the start of the array, take as many of that plan as you can without going over the number the user wants to buy:

```
var numUserWants = 150;
var purchases = {};
var cheapestAvailableProduct = myArr.shift();
while (numUserWants > 0 && cheapestAvailableProduct) {
    if (numUserWants <= cheapestAvailableProduct.licences) {
        purchases[cheapestAvailableProduct.id] = Math.floor(cheapestAvailableProduct.licences / numUserWants);
        numUserWants = cheapestAvailableProduct.licences % numUserWants;
    }
    cheapestAvailableProduct = myArr.shift();
}
```

At this point, `purchases` will now be a map of plan id to number:

```
purchases => {
  3: 3
  4: 1
}
```

This doesn't handle the case where over-purchasing is the cheapest option (eg: it's cheaper to buy 160 at `4x40`, instead of 150 at `3x40 + 1x25 + 1x5`), but it's probably a good start for you to tweaking.

Comment: This is better than a simple forEach loop? Maybe i'm missing something?

Comment: I'm sure the questioner is probably more interested in a strategy for finding the answer, rather than the merits of using for loops vs while loops.

Answer (score 1):

Just a simple `forEach` here. Take the number requested, begin calculating/mutating total based on option limits, and once the number requested is less than the option limit you have your final total, which wont be mutated any longer and returned from the function.

```
function calculateDiscountedTotal(numberRequested, myArr){
    var total;
    // loop, compare, calculate
    myArr.forEach(function(option) {
         if(numberRequested >= option.licenses){
            total = numberRequested * option.new_value_pr_licence
         }
    }
    if(total != undefined){
         return total;
    } else {
         // user never had enough for initial discount
         return "no discount price";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort the array first in terms of number of licenses and then get the object in which number of licenses is less than number of licenses to be bought (just less than the next item in the array which is greater than number of licenses to be bought)

```
var myArr = [
   {
      id: 3,
      licences: 100
      new_value_pr_licence: 40,
   },
   {
      id: 4,
      licences: 200,
      new_value_pr_licence: 25
   },
];
var numOfLic = 150;
myArr.sort( function(a,b){ return a.licences - b.licences } );
var selectedObj = myArr.reduce( function(prev,current){
  if ( current.licences > numOfLic )
  {
    return prev;
  }
});
console.log ( "pricing should be " + ( selectedObj.new_value_pr_licence * numOfLic )  );
```

Comment: If the plans were 1 for $5 or 100 for $100 and I wanted 101 licences, this algo would suggest buying 200 for $200 instead of 101 for $105.

Comment: @nickf yes, but OP never mentioned that combination of licenses can be purchased to get minimum cost value. But if you have managed to do that then cool :)